# My second cube won't run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game one normal cube change to a smaler cube.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSkift : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject myObject1;
    public GameObject myObject2;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            myObject1.SetActive (false);
            myObject2.SetActive (true);

        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            myObject2.SetActive(false);
            myObject1.SetActive(true);

        }

    }
}
```

This code is whats make it do so.
            But when i change to my small cube, it won't go anywhere. This scrip makes the cube run.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float forwardForce = 2000f;  
    public float sidewaysForce = 500f;  

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        // Add a forward force
        rb.AddForce(0, 0, forwardForce * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetKey("d"))  
        {

            rb.AddForce(sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("a"))  
        {

            rb.AddForce(-sidewaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (rb.position.y < -1f)
        {
            FindObjectOfType<GameManager>().EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Its on the smaller cube. So the smaller cube follows the bigger, this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Pl2føglPl1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player1;
    public Vector3 offset;


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        transform.position = player1.position + offset;
    }
}
```

when the bigger cube disappear, the little one won't start running. Pleas help if you can.

Comment: Attach your movement script to some parent object and not to the cude itself?

Comment: What do you mean??

Comment: If your object is inactive guess what happends with the scripts attached to it?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are trying to accomplish. Try rephrasing your question: What do you expect the two cubes to do? What does actually happen? Which script is attached to which GameObject?

Comment: @m.rogalski Please do not use "guess what happens". Either take your time to explain it to him or don't.

Comment: @Magnus Deactivating a GameObject deactivates any script attached to it. Usually its always a good idea to have a "Game Master" object in your scene when doing non-object-specific stuff like this. Inside of your Game Master object's script you just need to find the two GameObjects and you can use them as always, deactivating and activating them at will. But deactivating a GameObject from a script attached to the same GameObject is some form of GameObject suicide...

Comment: @MarkusAppel Read my comments. I've pointed out the issue clearly with my first comment. This question clearly is one of "give me solution, I don't care to read and learn"

Comment: @m.rogalski I disagree. You never mentioned that Scripts attached to GameObjects will also get deactivated. You need to already have a very basic understanding of how Scripting in Unity works to connect the strings. We were all beginners at some point, please remember that.

Comment: @MarkusAppel Yea I was a beginner but first of all, I've learned to use documentation as every beginner should.

Comment: @m.rogalski Oh please keep your ego to yourself. Unity is a great tool, but it is really overwhelming at first, especially for someone with little to no programming experience. Why shouldn't people ask their questions instead of munching through pages of unspecific documentation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165231/discussion-between-m-rogalski-and-markus-appel).

Comment: I'm sorry man. Im not so good at unity and coding. I just had a idea and the tried it.

Comment: @Magnus No need to apologize, we all have been started as beginners. Keep up the good work and don't be afraid to ask questions!

Comment: @Magnus I agree with Gábor, this site is for asking questions. Keep it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code i ended up using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerSkiftStørelse : MonoBehaviour {

    public Vector3 small;
    public Vector3 normal;
    public Vector3 high;
    public Vector3 offset;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.DownArrow))  //getkeydown??
        {
            transform.localScale = small;
        } 

        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.UpArrow))  //getkeydown??
        {
            transform.localScale = normal;
        } 

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what happens:

`public class PlayerMovement` 
makes normal cube move. But `public class PlayerSkift` does `myObject1.SetActive (false);` so normal cube gets deactivated. And it doesn't get `void FixedUpdate ()` event handler fired up anymore. So normal cube doesn't go anywhere, so smaller cube, following it, doesn't go anywhere either.

You need to create some "dummy" invisible GameObject, make your cubes children of if, attach `public class PlayerMovement` to it, so it always moves, regardless of inner children cubes states. And both children cubes will of course follow their parent's coordinates, since they are positioned relatively to parent. So you only move parent, and no need to synchronize cubes one to another, so you don't need `public class Pl2føglPl1` at all.

Comment: I have done as you said, but when i play and change, the 1. cube stais at its position, and the 2. cube starts from the starts. They are not following each other. and the camera isn't following the 2. cube. And the "dummy" is between the two cubes when i have changed.